# How scarce are souls?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I went into the game thinking enemies were unlimited, but after going through a few areas multiple times, enemies stopped respawning.

This suggests souls are a limited resource. If I lose, say, 2k souls too often, will this limit me in the end-game? Is it possible to continually obtain souls, or should every one be "cherished"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes and no.

Basically, after a while (as you mentioned), enemies stop spawning. So the souls stop flowing. However, there are ways around this.

1. **Infinitely Spawning Enemies.** Yup, you heard right. There are enemies that infinitely respawn; primarily the [Stone Soldiers](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/stone-soldier) in Drangleic Castle.
2. **Bonfire Ascetics.** Using bonfire Ascetics is a *great* way to farm souls, as once enemies stop spawning, this resets their cycle. The catch is: increased souls, and increased difficulty.

Comment: Thanks. Glad I won't permanently screw myself by accidentally diving off a cliff... twice. Are Bonfire Ascetics worth using early to farm, or are they more of an end game item?

Comment: They are fairly easy to come by, you can find them, purchase them, and even farm them.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, don't even think of this, even without ininite spawns the game provides like 20 times more souls than you need to reach lvl cap for any reasonable build. Additionally it is hard to lose souls from the boss fights, this is more than enough.

Comment: If you use bonfire ascetics you are "borrowing" monsters from the next playthrough, if you exhaust them again after a bonfire ascetic, the monsters in the area will also be gone in the next playthrough. If you use another one, you will get even stronger monsters, because you are now killing the ones from the next next playthrough, etc...

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. That's good to know. I guess I'll just enjoy the game instead of worrying.

Comment: @Kevin, what are you talking about? Going to next playthough is effectively applies bonfire ascetics to all bonfires. Mosters won't be gone, they will just be harder than you normaly expect for current playthrough.

Comment: @klm123 Ok here's an example: in NG you kill all monsters in Heide's tower so that they don't respawn anymore. If you use a bonfire ascetic there now, the monsters will respawn again, but they will be harder. This is because you are actually fighting the monsters from NG+ now, even though haven't started NG+ yet. Let's say you keep farming the tower and you reach the point again where the monsters don't respawn. You have now killed all monsters from NG+ as well, this means that if you start NG+ now and go to Heide's tower there will be no monsters.

Comment: @Kevin have you tried it? When I use ascetic in NG I get bonfire lvl 2 (so yes, you fight NG+ enemies then). If after that I chose to start NG+ this bonfire will become lvl 3, so I will fight NG++ enemies at this area now, I haven't checked, but I see no reason for them to be exhausted.

Answer (score 11):

With the latest patch, Dark Souls 2 gives you **unlimited souls**, available near the start of the game.

This is due to a change with the covenant [Company of Champions](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Company+of+Champions), accessible when you reach Majula (within 5 minutes in a new game).

In particular, one of the effect of this Covenant is as follows:

> Joining this covenant will give all non-special enemies **unlimited spawns** for the duration you're in the covenant (special enemies such as the Aldia Warlock in Shrine of Amana or the necromancers in Huntsman's Copse will not respawn).
>
> Once you leave, all enemies will return to the spawning condition they had before you joined.

This change was relatively recent.  It was updated after I have beaten it, but I noticed it during one of my more recent re-plays.

**Note:** Joining the Company of Champions is effective doing the same thing as burning a bonfire ascetic, except you can leave the covenant and reverse the upgraded enemies.  If you want to know how tough an area is after burning an ascetic, try out the covenant and test it out.

Comment: Oh! Good to know. I avoided joining the covenant because one of the player messages outside the stone said something like "heed the hint", and before you join, it says it will be an "arduous journey". I'm only level 27, so I do think know if it's a good idea for me to try yet. I'll look into it, thanks.

Comment: Read up on the wiki regarding what the covenant does.  Enemies are harder but if you're farming for souls, it is usually irrelevant.

Comment: rofl. I joined the covenant half an hour ago and started getting massacred everywhere I went. Now I need to find that cat. I'll keep this in mind for later in the game.

Comment: @Carcigenicate just note that burning an ascetic basically boosts the enemies the same amount, so this covenant is good to test out an area before upgrading it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually at the point now where using the covenant is a good way to get souls, so I have an idea about the difficulty.

Answer (score 7):

Just to make the topic complete. Another infinite source of souls is [White Soap Stones](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/multiplayer-items). By helping others to kill bosses and other enemies you get your part (up to 50%) of the souls and it has no influence on enemies in your world.

Answer (score 0):

Another source of souls is PvP.

The bridge at the start of the Iron Keep is filled with PvP signs. Killing an invader seems to net some (or all?) of the souls they're carrying.

It doesn't yield a lot, but if you're good at PvP, and at an active soul memory level, it's a source.