# Do all standard enemies respawn?

Tags: dark-souls

[The bosses never do](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/270667/148510), but certain standard enemies (which can hardly be considered as minibosses; there's four or so blowgun-wielders in a compact Blighttown cave) such as the blowdart snipers do not reappear when resting at a bonfire.

I haven't completed the game — are there more such foes?

Comment: You should find at least most by querying fandom.com in a search engine (e.g. `site:darksouls.fandom.com/wiki/ "non-respawning" enemies`) or searching the wiki directly. I'll verify all myself and will post an answer after fully completing the remastered version.

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294175/how-scarce-are-souls/294177#294177): in DS2 this works the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two non-respawning, clearly generic enemies:

The undead soldier in the [Undead Parish](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/undead-parish) that closes the gate behind the  Armored Tusk. If you manage to kill it before it can close the gate, it will not respawn. If you do not, it will stay on the other side of the gate until you kill it, and will still not respawn.

The first butcher in the depths has an accompanying [Undead Attack Dog](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/undead-attack-dog). Like the butcher herself, it will not respawn, but it is otherwise a generic enemy (albeit with 9 more HP, according to the wiki).

This is based off the original game - I assume the remaster did not change anything, but I can't confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above-mentioned, there is also:

- The Guardians of the Darkroot Forest (they de-aggro once you join the relevant covenant)
- The Hydras in Darkroot and Ash Lake
- The [Fang Boars/Armored Tusks](https://darksouls.fandom.com/wiki/Fang_Boar)
- The [Gargoyles](https://darksouls.fandom.com/wiki/Bell_Gargoyles#Boss_information) in Anor Londo
- The Anor Londo area can remove all spawns (apart from the Painting Guardians) by killing the illusion after the Boss fight, and replaces them with 2 Darkmoon Knights, and aggros the Darkmoon Knightess - all of which do not respawn (This cannot be undone).
- All bar one of the [Titanite Demons](https://darksouls.fandom.com/wiki/Titanite_Demon)
- [Bounding Demons of Izalith](https://darksouls.fandom.com/wiki/Bounding_Demon_of_Izalith), and 4 of the [Chaos Eaters](https://darksouls.fandom.com/wiki/Chaos_Eater) related to a Character Side Quest.

Comment: All are possibly listed on this page; you may want to expand your answer: https://darksouls.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Dark_Souls:_Minibosses